# How to get the current User inside a 'before save' operation hook?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

loopback.getCurrentContext() is null for me.  Why?  I need to grab the current User from the context.  The operation hook's ctx is not the same context and does not contain what I need as far as I can tell.

```
Customer.observe('before save', function checkPermission(ctx, next) {

  //do I have a loopback context that works?
  var context = loopback.getCurrentContext();
  console.log("context is: " + context);//null!
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old but this might help some people

according to loopback doc
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Using-current-context.html

> In LoopBack 2.x, this feature is disabled by default for compatibility reasons. To enable, add

first you need to add this to your customer model

```
"injectOptionsFromRemoteContext": true
```

then:

```
Customer.observe('before save', function checkPermission(ctx, next) {
  //ctx.options returns tokenid, userid & ttl
  console.log(ctx.options);
  return next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't PostgreSQL specific, but it is a bug.
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/878#issuecomment-128417677

Answer (score -4):

I think you should [add a pre-processing middleware](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Using+current+context#Usingcurrentcontext-Usecurrentauthenticateduserinremotemethods) to populate the context with the current user.

**/server/server.js**

```
app.use(loopback.context());
app.use(loopback.token());

app.use(function setCurrentUser(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.accessToken) {
        return next();
    }
    app.models.Customer.findById(req.accessToken.userId, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }
        if (!user) {
          return next(new Error('No user with this access token was found.'));
        }

        var loopbackContext = loopback.getCurrentContext();
        if (loopbackContext) {
              loopbackContext.set('currentUser', user);
        }
        next();
     });
});
```

**/common/models/customer.js**

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
module.exports = function(Customer) {
    Customer.observe('before save', function checkPermission(ctx, next) {

        var context = loopback.getCurrentContext();
        var currentUser = context && context.get('currentUser');
        console.log(currentUser);

        next();
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to add that code in server.js but no changes. Still null context.  So weird.  Does this have to do with using Postgres? There was a list of discussions about MongoDB and MySQL having a null context bug.

Comment: I'm going to try a total barebones project from scratch and see if I still get a null context.  If so, I'm calling it a bug and moving onto something else for production use.

Comment: Update, I've got a barebones project and loopback.getCurrentContext() inside a 'before save' is indeed null.  No idea if it's just me or a bug.  I'm using Postgres connector.

Comment: Yes I tried this code and I'm still getting a null context.  My enableHTTPContext is set to True and I've looked at all of the tutorials in the docs.  No worries guys. I'll try again next year.